# Clicking on Anchor tag produces elements to jump

Tags: html

When I click on an anchor tag (e.g #about), elements produce a strange behavior.
Normal Way:
![normal]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhEkZ.jpg

Strange Behavior after clicking on anchor link:
![strange]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thXCZ.jpg

I tried shifting the associated text with the anchor tag down (In this case the "Who are we?"), and every time I was shifting it down, triggering the anchor tag would produce the elements to go back at a strange position (as Image 2).

```html
                    <ul class="header_home__bar-container">
                        <li class="header_home__bar-container--el"><a href="#about" class="header_home__bar--button">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="header_home__bar-container--el"><a href="#services" class="header_home__bar--button">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="header_home__bar-container--el"><a href="#opinions" class="header_home__bar--button">Clients</a></li>
                        <li class="header_home__bar-container--el"><a href="#contactl" class="header_home__bar--button">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <h1 class="shift-down-small" id="about">Who are we?</h1>
```

**EDIT**: I found the anomalie that produces this; it's the image located at the right (the big green heart) which is set to the following css properties:

```css
    &--heart {


            &-1 {
                box-sizing: border;
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 15%;
                right: 0%;
            }
```

Removing the image fixes the issue, but obviously I need it! Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix! For people who may encounter this one day, the solution is just to remove (in my case was at least) the `overflow: hidden` css property from the parent element that wraps up all the child elements.

```css
.section_home_whatwedo {

    position: relative;
    **// overflow: hidden;**
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background: url('../design assets/SVG Main/SVG/AboutBG1.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    padding: 55rem 0rem;
    margin-top: -25rem;
    z-index: 6;
```